# Is it possible to have audio output source switch automatically with Xonar DG?

Tags: 14.04, alsa

I have an Asus Xonar DG card (which apparently has only been recently support as of Kernel 3.13).

I got the front audio working by (go figure) plugging the cases digital audio cord directly into the soundcard.

When I plug my headphones into the front port I have to manually select to output the sound there using the card.  I know this works in Windows, so the functionality is there - Does anyone know how to do it in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headphone detection is not implemented in the current version of the Linux driver.

Comment: Got a source for that?

Comment: [Source](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/pci/oxygen/xonar_dg.c) [code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/pci/oxygen/xonar_dg_mixer.c). Note that the driver never accesses GPIO 4.